# Displayed data does not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a function to fetch some data and display the data returned. The problem: The data does not display.

```
function Profile() {

    const profileUser = getData(userId)
    
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{profileUser?.name}</p>          
        </div>
    )
}
```

The `getData` is an asynchronous function returning fetching data from firebase while using `await` and returning an object.

Comment: if getData is async, you need to await it. The way you have it, the profileUser isn't reactive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

larz answer is good, but you may get a warning/error about useEffect being async. You aren't supposed to have an asyncronous useEffect method. There is a workaround though.

You need to define an async function inside of the useEffect hook that calls your async function. Then use that data to set the state. You need the state since that is what makes it reactive.

```
function Profile() {
    const [profileUser, setProfileUser] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchUserProfile = async () => {
        const user = await getData()
        setProfileUser(user);
      } 

      fetchUserProfile()
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{profileUser?.name}</p>          
        </div>
    )
}
```

Importantly, dont await your fetchUserProfile call, since again, the useEffect method is not async.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to store `profileUser` in state and then use `useEffect` to fetch that data when the component mounts

```
function Profile() {
    const [profileUser, setProfileUser] = useState();

    useEffect(async () => {
        const user = await getData(userId);
        setProfileUser(user);
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{profileUser?.name}</p>          
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You should not pass an async function to `useEffect`. `useEffect` expects a cleanup function or `undefined` as the return value. An async function always returns a promise, which is not what React's `useEffect` expects.

Comment: @3limin4t0r thanks! do you have any tip solving that issue?

Comment: @CyberguyGame Here's a tip to solve that: Use my answer instead. It's the bug free version. Unsure why the buggy answer was accepted.

Comment: @Jtcruthers you are absolutely right, your way works better! thanks for reminding me :)